# sql query: subtract from results the corresponding USD, YEN value which has Type='r'

Tags: sql, db2

I need help with a query. Consider the following table:

[image]

I need to select first the sum of each Code from table. I am doing it with simple sum and group by statement. Then I have to subtract the results from each code sum where **type='r'**

1) Say for first part of query, we will get 2 rows from SUM (one with total USD and one with total YEN)

2) Now I need to subtract from these results the corresponding USD, YEN value which has Type='r'

I have to do it inside SQL and not a stored procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select code, l.amount - r.amount
from
    (select code, sum(amount) as amount from my_table group by code) l
    left join (select code, sum(amount) as amount from my_table where type = 'r' group by code) r
    on l.code = r.code
```

Answer (score 4):

Why not use a WHERE statement to say `WHERE Type != 'r'` so that those values never even get added to sum in the first place...

```
SELECT `Code`, SUM(`Amount`) AS `Total` 
  FROM `Table` 
 WHERE `Type` != 'r' 
 GROUP 
    BY `Code`;
```

Something like that.

Comment: Thank you animuson, nice point. This is just a simple sample table. In the actual table & scenario I have to subtract and show the results somehow, requirements are a bit different.

Comment: this seems like a great solution, why dont you add some more information if the requirments are a bit different

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a single, simple query:

```
select
   code,
   sum(case when type = 'r' then (-1 * amount) else amount end) as sum
from 
   yourtable
group by
   code
```

Basically, you're changing the sign of the rows that have type = 'r', so when you sum all rows for a particular code you'll get the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be a single query?

I'd say SUM the total, then SUM the subcategory where Type='r', then subtract one from the other.

You *could* do this in one line of SQL, but I'm pretty sure it would be either joining the table with itself or using a subquery.  Either way, it's doing the same amount of work as the above.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yes it needs to be in a single query. I am confused how to subtract where sub category equals to each other). Duh, I have a got a vote down for my question :(

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select code, 
       sum(amount) gross_total,
       sum(case when type = 'r' then amount else 0 end) type_r_total,
       sum(case when type != 'r' then amount else 0 end) net_total
from yourtable
group by code;
```

to see the overall totals, type R only totals and non-type R totals for each currency on one row per currency, in a single pass.